# Wildfly - Reference "global" system properties in server-group system properties using ${} expression

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7

We use JBoss EAP 7.0.6.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.15.Final-redhat-1).
The problem is, that we cannot refer global system properties in server-group level.

The domain.xml looks like this:

```
<domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.1">
    ...
    <system-properties>
        <property name="global.ldap.url" value="ldaps://ldaphost:646" boot-time="true"/>
        ...
    </system-properties>

    <server-groups>
        <server-group name="sg1" profile="p1">
            ...
            <system-properties>
                <property name="ldap.url" value="${global.ldap.url}" boot-time="false"/>
                ...
            </system-properties>
        </server-group>
    </server-groups>
    ...
</domain>
```

When I start the servergroup with `/server-group=sg1:start-servers(blocking=true)`, it raises an error:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"domain-failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0158: Operation handler failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0211: Cannot resolve expression '${global.ldap.url}'"},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

It seems that global system properties are not propagated to servers at start.

Is this a wildfly bug or this use case of ${} expressions are not supported?

Comment: try with boot-time="true".

Comment: I've tried with boot-time="true" also, but unfortunately, it didn't help